# Angularjs pager lazy view render

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular controller with a pager, 10 per page.  When render I do the ng-repeat.  Question is when render there will be youtube video ID (item.videoID).  Instead of display the id I will need to get youtube video title.  I don't want to make service call to get all 100+ youtube video all at once.  Is there anyway I could do some type of lazy where it will just do youtube api title fetch what ever 10 is display (10 at current page)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it two ways:

1. Simply slice your response when you call it from angular service. On next page call increase the slice value.
2. Implement the pagination of your api. Pass page as parameter and returned results from server depending on page no and simply append to the results.

Hope this help...